# Is it "a big guy for you" or "extremely painful for you"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> BANE: No one cared who I was until I put on the mask.
>
> CIA: If I pull that off, would you die?
>
> BANE: It would be extremely painful….
>
> CIA: You’re a big guy!
>
> BANE: **For you!**
>
> --The Dark Knight Rises

I wonder what Bane tries to mean here.

Is it "a big guy for you" or "extremely painful for you"?

Comment: I don't know if what you've transcribed is an *exact copy* of some original, but the clue is right there in the orthography. The three dots (ellipsis) after Bane's *It would be extremely painful* indicate that ***he hasn't finished speaking***. Basically, he's saying *"It would be extremely painful for you"* while Cia is ***talking over him***.

Comment: What does "over" mean? louder than something?(OALD 14) @FumbleFingers

Comment: Yes - ordinarily, "talking over" would indeed primarily mean *speaking louder than someone else **at the same time***. But what we're looking at here is in principle a ***conversation*** (not a remotely feasible "real-world" conversation, of course - it's probably the final product honed over many hours by a team of script-writers). What I meant was that "structurally", Bane is making a single continuous statement from *"It would be..."* to *"...for you!"*. Cia interposes *"You're a big guy!"* while he's speaking, but that doesn't affect the grammar of Bane's ongoing statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "extremely painful for you".  Your alternative, "a big guy for you", doesn't make any sense.

When the agent asks his question, Bane's reply sounds like it's about Bane.  But after the agent replies, Bane clarifies that it would be painful for *the agent*, not *for Bane*.

It's a threat: he would hurt the agent if he tried to remove Bane's mask.

Comment: `"a big guy for you", doesn't make any sense` - sure it does, he's pointing out he's significantly stronger than CIA, another way of saying "pick on someone your own size" but having the bigger guy say it as a dismissal of the smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Hardy answered it thus:

*It was written meaning it would be painful for you, but I intoned it meaning "I'm a big guy for you."*

[Source.](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/23sxyu/director_steven_knight_here_joined_by_actor_tom/ch0b7ru)